# How to animate flipping motion in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to animate a card using `transition` with css and can't seem it working.

Here's the source script:

```
   .paper{
        border: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
    .pagesfront,
    .pagesback{
        background-color: #fff3d6;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        transform-origin: left;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
    
    }
    
    .pagesfront{
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .pagesback{
        z-index: 0;
    }
    
    .flipped .pagesfront,
    .flipped .pagesback{
        transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    }
```

Is there something I'm missing in the class pages where the transition comes in or is there something else?

Comment: Hello, please give us the HTML too.

Comment: Could you describe what won't work means? What do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you're putting the class `.flipped` on the wrong html element.
You do realize that the parent element of `.pagesfront` or `.pagesback` needs to have the class `.flipped` in order to get the flipping animation working, right?

If that was your intention, never mind what I said. If you meant to trigger the animation by adding the `.flipped` class to either `.pagesfront` or `.pagesback`, you might need to re-write that CSS code like this:

```
.pagesfront.flipped, 
.pagesback.flipped{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

(note there is no space between `.pagesfront/back` and `.flipped`.)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer, sorry to take your time but it turns out all i need is reopen the browser, what a weird case

Comment: its not a weird case. some time browser is unable to reload CSS . you dint need to reopen browser F5 will work fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).